# Android Ошибка вывода Toast

Tags: android

Имеется код:

```
protected String doInBackground(String[] args) {
        String login = loginView.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordView.getText().toString();
        String email = emailView.getText().toString();
        String phone = phoneView.getText().toString();
        String result;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_create_user);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("login", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(login, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&"
                    + URLEncoder.encode("phone", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(phone, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));
            String line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("Resul-----------",result);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            int success = jsonObject.getInt("success");
            //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivite.this, success, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

            String message = jsonObject.getString("message");
            Log.e("message-----------",message);

            if(success==1){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivite.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
            else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegisterActivite.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

        pDialog.cancel();
    }
```

Судя по ошибке причина в Toast. В чем ошибка?

```
E/Resul-----------: {"success":1,"message":"\u041f\u043e\u043b\u044c\u0437\u043e\u0432\u0430\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c \u0434\u043e\u0431\u0430\u0432\u043b\u0435\u043d."}
E/message-----------: Пользователь добавлен.
W/dalvikvm: threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa000f180)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
                   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
                      at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
                      at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
                      at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
                      at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
                      at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite$createUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivite.java:167)
                      at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite$createUser.doInBackground(RegisterActivite.java:111)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 
I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
            Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/dalvikvm: threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
            Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
E/WindowManager: Activity com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@a1280c58 that was originally added here
                 android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@a1280c58 that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
                     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
                     at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite$createUser.onPreExecute(RegisterActivite.java:122)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
                     at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite.Registration(RegisterActivite.java:92)
                     at com.example.danilshik.myapplication.RegisterActivite$1.onClick(RegisterActivite.java:73)
                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: потому что нельзя из метода doInBackground лезть в UI - что и написано в ошибке.

Comment: Если в двух словах, то к UI надо обращаться в `onPostExecute`.

Comment: @Suvitruf все спасибо, понял

Answer (score 0):

я сам относительно недавно начал изучение андроид,но насколько я помню, toast можно выводить только в основном потоке. Как вариант можно в вашем классе MyTask extends AsyncTask реализовать интерфейс с методом например doSomething(), а класс активити, в котором запускаете другой поток, имплементировать от этого интерфейса и переопределить статичный метод и вызвать его в onPostExecute().

что-то типа этого

Класс MyTask:

```
    public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private MyCall mMyCall;

    public MyTask(MyCall myCall){
        mMyCall = myCall;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
     //ваш код
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute() {

            mMyCall.doSomething();
    }

    public interface MyCall{

        void doSomething();
    }
}
```

класс MainActyvity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyTask.MyCall {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       //ваш код

       new ParseTask(this).execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
          Toast.makeText(this,"какой-то текст", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Comment: Не делайте так. У вас активити течет при поворотах экрана. Если вы начинаете изучать андроид, начинайте правильно: с архитектурных компонентов.

Comment: Ok,учту,спасибо